# Match a target spectrum

Tags: discrete-signals

I'm working on rolling noise emissions from cars. I have a model for rolling noise emissions which gives me sound pressure levels in third octave bands (29 in total, between 20Hz and 8kHz), depending on vehicle speed, and road/tyre combinaison.

I'd like to fit a real recording of tire/road noise to the model, while keeping the spectral properties of the recording. The signal of rolling noise is mainly stochastic[image]

In blue, the spectrum of the recording using Welch's method, and in red, the levels i'd like to reach.

What kind of methods can i use in this particular case?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't really understand – usually, you fit the model to the data, not the data to the model. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: So you want your recording to sound like your model? Why don't you apply a multiband equalizer? You already know the desired gain in dB for each band.

Comment: I want a realistic sound of rolling tire noise, that's why i use a recording, and i want to fit it to the true levels given by the spectrum in red.